# Doubly Linked Circular List problem solving

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to understand the answer to this question.

> We want to store a  collection of 100 StudentMark objects in a list. A
> student mark object contains only a student id number, which takes a
> single word (4 bytes) and a mark, which takes another word.
>
> We choose a Doubly Linked Circular List as our implementation of a
> list ADT. All pointers also take one word of memory. StudentMark
> objects are not stored directly in the linked list nodes but are
> allocated elsewhere in memory and only a pointer to each StudentMark
> object is stored in each linked list node.
>
> How many words of memory are required to store all the linked list
> nodes and all the StudentMark objects?
>
> Do not include the header node that points to the first node in the
> linked list in your count.

**Doubly Linked Circular List**:

[image]

I assumed the answer was 400

Reasoning:

- 2 words of memory for every object as each object has a sutdentID & a single word which take 1 word of memory each, so, 2*100 = 200
- 2 words of memory for each object, as each object has two pointers coming out from it so, 2*100 = 200
- 200 + 200 = 400

But apparently the answer is 500

Comment: 2 words per StudentMark + 3 words (next pointer, previous pointer, data pointer) per node, (2+3)*100=500 in total.

Comment: @SUTerliakov in the example image above is the data pointer the numbers? in essence the value of each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyphrase in the description is this one:

> StudentMark objects are **not stored directly** in the linked list nodes but are allocated elsewhere in memory and only **a pointer** to each StudentMark object **is stored** in each linked list node.

The word used by that pointer (marked in bold in the above quote) was missing in your calculation.

A more detailed picture of the linked list structure would be like this one:

```
           ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐        
  ┌────────│─────────────────────────────────────┐        │
  │        ▼                                     ▼        │
  │ ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐ │
  └─── prev   │◄──── prev   │◄──── prev   │◄──── prev   │ │
    │  next ─────►│  next ─────►│  next ─────►│  next ────┘  
    │  data   │   │  data   │   │  data   │   │  data   │
    └───│─────┘   └───│─────┘   └───│─────┘   └───│─────┘
        │             │             │             │
        ▼             ▼             ▼             ▼
    ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐   ┌─────────┐
    │  ID     │   │  ID     │   │  ID     │   │  ID     │
    |  mark   |   |  mark   |   |  mark   |   |  mark   |
    └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘   └─────────┘
```

In each "column" in this diagram there are 5 words, so if the linked list has 100 entries, the total number of words is 500.